# c++ 2D array using pointers and memory allocation (new/delete)

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to build a 2D array which has dynamic dimensions. I could use the vector class for this, but my assignment prohibits it. So I came up with the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "1" << endl;
    int** 2DArr = new int*[5];
    cout << "2" << endl;
    for(unsigned int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        2DArr[index] = new int[5];
        cout << "3";
    }
    cout <<"\n4"<<endl;
    for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        cout << "5 " << endl;
        for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            cout << "6 " << endl;
            2DArr[row][col] = 1;
            cout << "7" << endl;
            cout << 2DArr[row][col];
            cout << "8" << endl;
        }
        cout << "8" << endl;
    }
    cout << "9" << endl;
}
```

The code above is an example of what I am trying to accomplish, along number at each step. The above code seems to hang right after "6" is printed. Can anyone explain to me why the above code doesn't work and how I could fix it? My understanding is that 2D arrays made of pointers can be accessed using [], yet for some reason, the above hangs at the exact line i'm trying to assign 1 to the 2D array. My guess is that it expects an adress and not an int, but I;m not sure. Please show me howto assign an actual integer at step 6.

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's good to have one that doesn't contain basic syntax errors.

Comment: Besides that, the expression `2DArr[5] = new int[5]` will write to the *sixth* element in the five-element array. Always.

Comment: Change the part that Some programmer dude mentioned and give the variable a valid name (not allowed to begin with a number) and you got a working program. That said, in a real program, you'd want to wrap this in a class, creating your own array class, to make sure that the memory is freed afterwards. Might be a good exercise for you.

Comment: Thanks guys, Due to this being an assignment, I cannot copy and paste the actual code so I have to write a similar code while still being different. The original code did have variables instead of constants, but one of the variable used was the wrong one, probably due to me copy pasting the code from another section. The fix worked. Thank you very much!